# Sql query to extract constant value in a column between 10 days

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query which will pull me the employee **id's** which has stale data for a month in **column1**.

**For ex:**

I am maintaining a table where i will store power consumed by an employee per day. Now I want to pull out the **emp id's** who have maintained power at `30wats` constantly for a month.

Comment: Some example data would help

Comment: For ex

There are 100 employees in an organization.
emp 1 is using 30 watts power per day and he has used the same 30 watts for a month. emp 2 has used 50 wats power per day and has maintained the same for a month. so my query should pull out emp 1 and emp 2

Comment: So if I understand that right you want all the employees that have the same number in the watts column for a specific time. is that usage always exactly the same or does it differ slightly?

Comment: Yes I want the employees who have same number in the watts column for a month. The usage differ. like emp 1 may have maintainted 30 watts for a month and emp 2 may have maintained 50 watts for a month and empl 5 may have maintained 100 watts for a month. i want emp 1,2, and 5 (who have maintained same value for a month)

Comment: Hi There, Sorry for the inconvenience. It is far enough if the usage value is exactly the same. say, employees who have maintained 30 wats per day all through a month.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT emp_id
FROM your_table
GROUP BY emp_id
HAVING ( COUNT ( DISTINCT RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY emp_id) > 1;
```

This might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT empId,TOTAL_SUM FROM 
    (SELECT empId,SUM(CNT) AS TOTAL_SUM FROM 
        (SELECT empId,SNAPSHOT_DAY,COUNT(*) AS CNT 
         FROM emp_details 
         WHERE power_usage=300 
         AND SNAPSHOT_DAY>TO_DATE('20150218','yyyymmdd') - 30 
         AND SNAPSHOT_DAY<=TO_DATE('20150218','yyyymmdd') 
         GROUP BY empId,SNAPSHOT_DAY
        ) 
    GROUP BY empId
    )
WHERE total_sum > 29;
```